# Integrate SalesForce with IntelliJ IDEA via SVN

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, salesforce, issue-tracking

Is it possible to integrate Issue tracking provider such as SalesForce with IntelliJ IDEA?

A user will able to get a list of open issues from SalesForce with IntelliJ ?

thanks.

Comment: Given that svn is a tool for source code version management, not one for tracking defects/issues, I would suggest that it wouldn't be involved in any integration between SalesForce and IntelliJ.

Comment: IntelliJ has its own SVN plug-in. I just wanted to know if there is a SalesForce <-> IntelliJ integration tool. SVN is just my SCC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if one already exists, but you can make web services calls to salesforce.com to access your data, so you should be able to build a plugin to do this.

Comment: I've built one for TortoiseSVN. But IntelliJ has a SVN plug-in of its own, So there is no need for TortoiseSVN.